# Warning in Eureka home page, May i know what it meant for?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

[image]I can see **EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE** 
in Eureka home page May i know what it meant for?

Comment: Everything working alright except the warning in the home page

Answer (score 0):

It means it might be showing you the instances under **Instances currently registered with Eureka** even the services are not running anymore. This is because Eureka server does not de-register the instance if the services are stopped abruptly.